Lebesgue-Vitali theorem and the characteristic function of $\mathbb{Q}$
The Lebesgue-Vitali theorem tell us that almost everywhere continuous functions on a closed interval are Riemann Integrable. I understand that the characteristic function of $\mathbb{Q}$ defined on $[0, 1]$ is almost everywhere continuous as it is simply the constant function $0$ with countably many discontinuities on $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]$. Nevertheless, it is not Riemann integrable. I think I don't understant almost everywhere continuity on this case. I would appreciate any help.

Almost everywhere continuity means that the set of points where the function is not continuous has measure zero. The indicator of the rationals is continuous nowhere, because the rationals are a dense set.
Notably, if $f=g$ almost everywhere and $g$ is continuous, then $f$ need not be continuous almost everywhere! This highlights an important difference between topology and measure: dense sets (which are large topologically) can have zero measure.

@Kham Bodrogi: To restate a point made in this answer, note that there is a logical distinction between the discontinuity set of a function and the discontinuity set of another function that is obtained from the original function by changing the values of the original function in some places ("some" in your case being a countably infinite set).

The characteristic function you mention is discontinuous at every point, and $[0,1]$ has Lebesgue Measure 1.
